# Problem with plugins installation (2.18.3)

Tags: qgis, python, error, plugins

I'm using QGIS version 2.18.3. When I try to install a plugin, a message appears after the installation progress[image: error message]

This problem occured not only with this plugin, but with every plugin I tried to install (I tried at least 30 different). How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have several versions of python on your system? Or non-ASCII letters in your Windows username?

Comment: My username consists only of english letters. As for python i can't say it for sure, from a quick search i think i have only one version of python, 2.7.5 as it says in the message but in the results of the search i can see a lot of python 2.7 files. I repeat i'm not sure about that